# AutoHotkey unreliable behaviour in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Simple AutoHotkey script that should open Firefox is unreliable in Windows 10.

```
#f::Run firefox.exe
```

Sometimes it opens Firefox, but other times it opens 'Feedback Hub' window.

It looks like sometimes AutoHotkey scripts are ignored or maybe Windows 10 native shortcuts take precedence.

AutoHotkey version: v1.1.25.02, loaded as regular user (not run as administrator)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `$#f::Run firefox.exe` - you can read about the various modifiers including **$** here https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols